# Getting Client-side validation to work

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Situation: project created by `dotnet new webapp`

My Razor Pages page is working with server side validation, that is, `ModelState` is returning the correct value accordingly.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#client-side-validation), am I reading it correctly that all I have to do is to add the following two scripts (in addition to jQuery already in _layout) for client side validation to work?

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I tried but client side validation does not take place. Developer Tools showed the scripts loaded fine and there were no run time script errors.

Are any additional attributes needed in the Html besides those shown in the link?

My Html in `Index.cshtml` is:

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="userId">User id: </label>
     <input type="text" name="userId" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="userId" class="text-danger" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="password">Password: </label>
     <input type="password" name="password" />
     <span asp-validation-for="password" class="text-danger" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
//jQuery loads before this
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

`Index.cshtml.cs` is:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
  [Required]
  public string userId { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string password { get; set; }

  public ActionResult OnGet()
  {
    return Page();
  }
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IndexModel model)
  {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) //works fine
      return RedirectToPage("/notvalid");
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your sample html or a link to it? The validate javascript works with the html form  tag's submit.  So if you use an ajax post on an event other than under form submit,  it will bypass the client side validation.

Comment: It depends on how you are rendering the HTML controls here, which means you haven't given us enough information, please create a [mcve]. Also, make sure jQuery is defined *before* the validation scripts.

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: You're missing the use of `asp-for` on your input controls, which adds `data-val` attributes to the input controls that are picked up by the jQuery-based validation to do its magic. The docs you linked to explain this process in more detail.

Comment: I didn't add that because according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1, it merely fills in the value for the `for` attribute in a `<label>` element. I will try adding.

Comment: Sure - the label doesn't participate in the validation process but the input tag-helper [does a lot more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-input-tag-helper).